# prime number for summation

Tags: summation, prime-factorization

I need list of numbers that are not sum of previous numbers in that list. And also given any number, If it is possible to generate that number by summing elements(one or multiple time) from the list, There shall be only one combination that can generate that specific number.
for example, I understand 2 and 3 simultaniously cannot be in the list, cause given a number say 10, it can be expressed as 2+2+2+2+2 or, 3+3+2+2.

I guess the problem is kind of like prime numbers in case of summation instead of multiplication. Like, given any number, there can be only one prime factorization, I am willing to find such "Primes for summation".

is there such known sequence known? or how can I generate such numbers?
Thank you.

P.S. I have searched in the internet for a while, but haven't found any specific link. Any link will also be very helpful.

Comment: Hint: if $a,b \geq 1$ are distinct integers, $a + \ldots +a=b+\ldots+b$ (the first sum has $b$ terms, the second sum has $a$ terms)…

Comment: Oh right... So, there cannot be such list...